# laravel 5.2 storage is not showing images

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, storage

I am saving files in storage folder on below path. File exist since last 6 months. It was working fine and showing files very well. Suddenly started showing a white box instead of image.

```
storage/app/public/modules/applications/1/borrower_picture
```

Image path:

```
http://project.seedout/application_images/1/borrower_picture/picture_8.png
```

Image showing route code:

```
Route::get('application_images/{borrower_id}/{foldername}/{filename}', function ($borrower_id, $foldername, $filename) {
     $path = storage_path('app/public/') . 'modules/applications/' . $borrower_id . '/' . $foldername . "/" . $filename;
     if (!File::exists($path)) {
         $path = config("seedout.admin.default_gravatar");
     }
     $file = File::get($path);
     $type = File::mimeType($path);
     $response = Response::make($file, 200);
     $response->header("Content-Type", $type);
     return $response;
})->name('application_images');
```

`$path` variable shows below path.

```
F:\xampp\htdocs\seedout\storage\app/public/modules/applications/1/borrower_picture/picture_8.png
```

Comment: What is the File class? Is that an alias for Storage?

Comment: No its laravel File Façade. Further there is question in my mind, Is this way of viewing picture is good or we should use direct asset path to view files. Mean using symlink use direct path of picture instead of route???

Comment: Because some time when I refresh page, picture get blank. Its weird.